# Laravel 6 custom login URL with attributes

Tags: php, laravel

I have login route with attributes from database:

`Route::get('/{url_attribute}&={id_message}', 'AuthController@index')->name('login');`

How to define `url_attribute` and `id_massage` in conttroler for redirect back when password is wrong? Login URL works with `function index`

```
 public function index($url_attribute, $id_message)
    {
    return view('login')->with(['url_attribute' => $url_attribute,'id_message' => $id_message]);
    }
```

problem is here with $url_attribute and $id_message:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    request()->validate([
        'id_message' => 'required',
        'sms_code' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('id_message', 'sms_code');


    if ($user=User::where($credentials)->first()) {
        auth()->login($user);

        return redirect()->intended('dashboard')->with('success','');
        }

    return Redirect::to("login")->with(['url_attribute' => $url_attribute,'id_message' => $id_message])->with('error','');
}
```